# Java - How to disable a key input temporarily when I receive a KeyEvent?

Tags: java, key, keyevent

What I want to do: In a JTextPane, when I press Tab, insert something into it.

The problem I met: After something was inserted, there will be a '\t' inserted, too. I don't want it.

The reason, I guess, is that the Tab still provides a '\t'.
But I googled and found nothing about how to disable it.

So how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to replace the key binding been used by the text pane.  If you look, there are examples of how do to this.

Comment: before inserting your new content, get the old and remove the `\t`